# Unable to Edit tag wiki while edit pending?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

A tag (safety) was edited and showed up in the edit queue. The suggested edit, while better than the existing description, was not proper. Trying to make an edit/suggestion of my own, I went to the tag page, and had no option to edit, even though I could on other tags (two I checked were Arduino and Microcontroller). Is this by design, or is this an error?

When edits to questions show up in the edit queue, you have the option to change/fix/edit instead of simply accepting or rejecting. Shouldn't the tag wiki edits have the same options?

Comment: I assume the reason would be unlike a regular edit which you can always do anyway when you have access to the queue you need 20k to do a wiki tag edit without approval. It would be good idea though if it could just go back in the queue for a few others to check.

Comment: @PeterJ or atleast a message saying "Edit Pending, please try again later"

Answer (score -2):

Similar to how pending edits work on regular posts, you cannot edit if there is a pending suggested edit in the queue for the post.

The edit will need to be approved/rejected before other edits can be made.

Comment: But regular posts edits in the review queue have an option of "Approve, Edit, Reject, Skip". Tag Wiki Edits only have Approve or Reject. And if you choose edit, it also has a little checkbox saying if the suggested edit was helpful or not.